# Inquiry about JavaScript on Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I can't find out the problem. I can't print the word "hello" in the canvas but it seems my codes are logical. I have tried figuring the problem out for 30 minutes.

```js
var words = ["buddha", "canoe", "dice", "elephant"];
var canvas;
var ctx;
//var timer;
var getrandomphoto = -1;

function play() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "20px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillText = ("hello", 100, 100);
  // getrandomphoto= getrandomnumber(); 
  // document.getElementById("hk").src= words[getrandomphoto]+".jpg" ; 

}

function getrandomnumber() {
  var random_num = Math.random() * words.length;
  var random_int = Math.floor(random_num);
  return random_int;

}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#message {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<img id="hk" src=".jpg" alt="no photo" width="200" /></img>
<br/>
<br/>
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="200" width="500"></canvas>
<br/>
<button onclick="play()">Play</button>
<button onclick="moveleft()">&larr;</button>
<button onclick="moveright()">&rarr;</button>
<p id="message">Press Play</p>
<p>Plate X-coordinate: <span id="plateX"></span>
  <p>Word X-coordinate: <span id="wordX"></span>
    <p>Distance: <span id="dist"></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that `ctx.fillText` is a function but you're not calling it with any arguments. Thus you need to call it with arguments instead of setting it equal to `("hello", 100, 100)`:

`ctx.fillText("hello", 100, 100);`

See working example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    #message {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var words = ["buddha", "canoe", "dice", "elephant"];
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    //var timer;
    var getrandomphoto = -1;

    function play() {
      canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.font = "20px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.fillText("hello", 100, 100); // change ctx.fillText = ("hello", 100, 100) to ctx.fillText("hello", 100, 100)
      getrandomphoto= getrandomnumber(); 
      document.getElementById("hk").src= words[getrandomphoto]+".jpg" ; 

    }

    function getrandomnumber() {
      var random_num = Math.random() * words.length;
      var random_int = Math.floor(random_num);
      return random_int;

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="hk" src=".jpg" alt="no photo" width="200" /></img>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" height="200" width="500"></canvas>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="play()">Play</button>
  <button onclick="moveleft()">&larr;</button>
  <button onclick="moveright()">&rarr;</button>
  <p id="message">Press Play</p>
  <p>Plate X-coordinate: <span id="plateX"></span>
    <p>Word X-coordinate: <span id="wordX"></span>
      <p>Distance: <span id="dist"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry. I am too new to Javascript.